# Line integral of a vector field?

Tags: integration, vector-spaces, parametric, curves, greens-theorem

First of all, sorry for the sketch.. I would be glad if you show me another ways to improve this drawn.

I'm studying Line integrals, and this question is really boring me. Please, can someone put the steps of the resolution WITHOUT the Green's theorem, and parameterizing in $t$ variable?

The question:

> Let $C$ be the oriented curve (see the image). Evaluate $$\int_C (x^3 y^2 + y)dx +xdy$$

The answer must be $-1/8$

Image:

[image]

Comment: What is your try ?

Comment: If this question is really boring to you, why do you think it interests anyone else?

Comment: When I tried to solve the question, I reached the same value, but positive... And YES Karl, I think yes, otherwise I wouldn't posting it, don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral is sum
$$
I = I_1 + I_2 + I_3 = \int\limits_{y=x^2} + \int\limits_{y=1} + \int\limits_{x=0}
$$
Ok, let's evaluate.
$$
I_1 = \int\limits_{y=x^2} (x^3y^2 + y)\,dx + x\,dy =
\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=1} (x^3(x^2)^2 + x^2)\,dx + x\cdot2x\,dx =\\= 
\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=1} (x^7 + 3x^2)\,dx = \frac98
$$
$$
I_2 = \int\limits_{y=1} (x^3y^2 + y)\,dx + x\,dy = \int\limits_{x=1}^{x=0} (x^3 + 1)\,dx = -\frac54
$$
$$
I_3 = \int\limits_{x=0} (x^3y^2 + y)\,dx + x\,dy = 0
$$
Now
$$
I = I_1 + I_2 + I_3 = \frac98 - \frac54 = -\frac18.
$$

We could simplify this integral a little:
$$
\oint (x^3y^2 + y)\,dx + x\,dy = \oint x^3y^2\,dx + \oint y\,dx + x\,dy = 
\oint x^3y^2\,dx + \oint d(xy) = \oint x^3y^2\,dx
$$

Or to use Green:
$$
I = \iint  \left(\frac{\partial(x^3y^2 + y)}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial(x)}{\partial x}\right)dx\,dy = \iint 2x^3y\,dx\,dy = \int_0^1 x^3\,dx \int\limits_{y=x^2}^{y=1} 2y\,dy =\\= \int_0^1 x^3(x^4 - 1)\,dx =\frac18-\frac14 = -\frac18
$$

Comment: Thank You Michael, Thank you very much!! Please, can you explain me why and how you made this: $$
 \oint d(xy)
$$ ?

Comment: @BrunodeAssis It's property of line integral